# Classification of Finite Coxeter Groups Bjorner

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

While Humphreys gives a classification of finite irreducible Coxeter groups by their "geometric representation", Bjorner and Brenti (Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups) leave it as an exercise in Chapter 1 (question 4). At this point, they have covered only basic definitions, the exchange condtion and the deletion condition and given a few examples. The question is as follows:

> Show with a direct and elementary argument that the Coxeter diagram $D$ of a finite irreducible Coxeter group must satisfy the following graph-theoretic requirements:
>
> 1. $D$ is a tree
> 2. $D$ has at most one vertex of degree 3 and none of higher degree
> 3. $D$ has at most one marked (i.e. label $\geq 4$) edge
> 4. If $D$ has a degree 3 vertex, then all edges are unmarked
>
> Hint: In the presence of any violation, exhibit an element of infinite order.

It is not so clear to me how to prove my given sequence of words is of irreducible words, or even a sequence of strictly increasing length.

For instance, consider $\tilde{A_2} = \langle s_1, s_2, s_3 \mid s_i^2 = 1, (s_is_j)^3 = 1 \rangle$ for $j \neq i$. This group's Coxeter diagram contains a cycle, and we wish to find  an element of infinite order. Such an element is given by $(s_1s_2s_3)$. By the "word property" (Theorem 3.3.1) they prove two chapters later, $(s_1s_2s_3)^n$ cannot be reduced, as it contains no instance of $s_is_{i+1}s_i$ or $s_i^2$. However, this is not an elementary argument. Any insight into how to prove this with elementary arguments would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you interpreting "exhibit an element of infinite order" as meaning "exhibit elements of arbitrarily large order"? That's not what it says and it is not what it means! In the example you describe, $s_1s_2s_3$ has infinite order.

Comment: Oh, of course, I think I misread it. I'll edit my post. While I can see that this suffices, looking at it from the perspective of proving that $s_1s_2s_3$ having infinite order doesn't immediately seem to make it any easier for me.

Comment: I have looked at the book, and I am afraid that I cannot at the moment see how to solve this exercise using only the tools covered so far in the book.